# Select every other 2 table rows with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am currently using this code to add a class to every other row in my table.

```
$(".stripeMe tr:even").addClass("alt");
```

However, on another table I'd like to add a class to rows 3,4, 7,8, 11,12 and so on...

Is this possible?

Comment: pls provide a snippets of table structure!

Comment: its a simple table structure: <table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
$(".stripeMe tr:nth-child(4n)").add(".stripeMe tr:nth-child(4n-1)").addClass("alt");​​​​​​​​
//or...
$("tr:nth-child(4n), tr:nth-child(4n-1)", ".stripeMe").addClass("alt");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[You can see this working here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ph6jS/).

Using this:

```
$(".stripeMe tr:nth-child(4n), .stripeMe tr:nth-child(4n-1)").addClass("alt");​​​​​​​​
```

[gets different results](http://jsfiddle.net/ndn67/) (namely in webkit, possibly others).

Comment: How can i apply a different css class to the first 2 rows only now? Thanks btw!

Comment: @Mark - If you mean just the **very** first 2, then like this:  `$(".stripeMe tr:lt(2)").addClass("otherClass");​​​​`

Answer (score 3):

With the `:nth-child´ selector: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
$(".stripeMe tr:nth-child(4n), .stripeMe tr:nth-child(4n-1)").addClass("alt");
```

Comment: @RoToRa - Open it in webkit :)

Comment: @BlairHippo - Don't test in a single browser, try chrome/safari...selectors that are sometimes implemented by the browser and emulated by jquery if not present may not always have the same behavior, which is the case here.

Comment: Correct, it does not work in Chrome, is there a correction for this? thanks

Comment: Well then jQuery is broken there. Another good reason not to use it :-)

Comment: @Mark - See my answer for a cross-browser solution

Comment: @RoToRa - I don't agree at all, it's the webkit selector not working, the jQuery emulation (e.g. view it in IE) works fine....write this without jQuery, let me know how verbose that gets :)

Comment: @Nick It's not the selector. Using the selector in CSS works fine in Webkit. http://jsfiddle.net/Pd4Z3/

Comment: @RoToRa - Then the problem is still in Sizzle/Webkit :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` function to filter the set any way you like:

```
$(".stripeMe tr")
.filter(function(i){ return (i % 4) >= 2; })
.addClass("alt");
```

This will keep the items with index 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11 and so on. Note that the index is zero based, so the third row as index two.

Answer (score 1):

I made a different approach for this problem using a for loop and .eq() method.

```
var a = 2; // start from 2 because eq() counts from 0
var b = 3; // start from 3 because eq() counts from 0
var total = $('.stripeMe td').length;

for (i = 0; i <= total; i++){
    if (i == a){
        $('.stripeMe tr:eq('+a+')').css('background', 'red');
        a+=4;
    }
    else if (i == b){
        $('.stripeMe tr:eq('+b+')').css('background', 'blue');
        b+=4;
    }
};
```

​